# Highlight a specific cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to highlight a specific cell in my pandas dataframe. I can grab the exact position using the `.loc[]` function. I've tried to look at some examples using `df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background color: yellow' ...]` but I am not sure how to pass in the exact position I am trying to access to format.

My dataframe has a multi index so to access a specific cell I use: `df.loc[(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5),col1]` and this would indicate the cell I want formatted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a specific cell, you can do:

```
# toy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'i1':[0,0,0,1,1,1],
                   'i2':[0,1,2,0,1,2],
                   'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}).set_index(['i1','i2'])

subsets = pd.IndexSlice[(0,1), 'col1']
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: yellow", subset=subsets)
```

Which will hightlight the cell `[(0,1), 'col1']`.

Comment: One more question, how could I highlight some of the indices? For example, highlighting 'i1'

Comment: it's easy for first level index `subsets = pd.IndexSlice['i1','col1']`, will be tricky for other levels though.

Comment: Sorry, I mean specifically highlighting the index name, not entries within the table

Comment: For that, I have to say that I don't know.